# Python insert YAML in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, yaml, pymongo

Folks,
  Having a problem with inserting the following yaml document into MongoDB:

works:

```
---
URLs: 
  - "http://www.yahoo.com":
    intensity: 5
    port: 80
```

does not:

```
---
URLs: 
  - "foo":
    intensity: 5
    port: 80
```

The only difference is the url.  Here is the python code:

```
    stream = open(options.filename, 'r')
    yamlData = yaml.load(stream)
    jsonData = json.dumps(yamlData)
    io = StringIO(jsonData)
    me = json.load(io)

    ... calling classes, etc, then
    self.appCollection.insert(me)
```

err:

```
 bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'http://yahoo.com' must not contain '.'
```

So, what is the correct way to transform this YML file? :)

Thanks!

Comment: accoring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201661/key-must-not-contain-error-in-pymongo, I should replace '.' in keys with _  does not sound fun.  is this the correct approach?

Comment: Best not to use arbitrary keys from the outside world with MongoDB. Using URLs as keys is questionable practice. For example, now you can't index all the URLs. Better to redesign your schema so documents are like {"url": "http://example.com"}. Then you can declare an index on "url" and search for them, and now you don't have to replace dots with other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use "." in field names (i.e. keys). If you must, then replace occurences of "." with the unicode representation "\uff0E".

Hope this helps.

Comment: how would i go about looping and replacing all `.` with `\uff0E` ?

Comment: `me.replace(".", "\uff0E")`

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Sorry I used "me" in reference to the string object, which would you be `io` in your example?

Comment: AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: stream = open(options.filename, 'r').read().replace(".", "\uff0E")

Comment: thank you ! almost there... "http://www．yahoo．com/"  how do i get rid of the space?

Comment: since the file has a ton of spaces anyways... why is the code adding an extra space?

Answer (score 1):

As the errors says, you have errors in your key. MongoDB uses dot for nested document keys, you cannot have a key that contains dot as part of the key.

Comment: what would be a proper way to transform this to have this proper JSON document to be saved?

Comment: It is really a application level conversion which need to be done meaningfully to accommodate scenarios you want to use. I.e. do you want to ever reverse convert?