# Iterating Through Keys for String Replacement in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, yaml, pymongo

I'm trying to insert YAML (individual lines of JSON) into mongoDB via pyMongo. A few of my keys contain periods, which gives an error `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'job.no' must not contain '.'`. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21201716/297780), I'll need to iterate through my keys to replace the period, which makes sense.

The issue I'm having is that my data is messy. My json contains layers of nested objects, I won't know before-hand what the string containing a period is, or where it is (which level). Here's a small sample of my data.

```
{"uuid":"94e31-02f59","project":{"name":"oasis","job.no":215493452,"subset":"beta"},"time":1412371841024}
```

I have a function that recursively iterates over my JSON. I've tried a few variations, but it either flattens my JSON (no more nested objects) or only returns the first object. I want to maintain the structure of my input.

```
def keyCleaner(line):
    for k, v in line.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            keyCleaner(v)
        else:
            nK = k
            if "." in k:
                nK = k.replace(".", "_")
            return nK, v
```

Here's what it currently returns:

```
(u'uuid', u'94e31-02f59')
```

What I'd like for it to return is:

```
{"uuid":"94e31-02f59","project":{"name":"oasis","job_no":215493452,"subset":"beta"},"time":1412371841024}
```

But I'm not seeing how this comes together. Can anyone help?

Comment: just an idea, why don't you convert everything to string, something like `json.dumps()`, fix the period and change it back to json `json.loads()`, just an idea.

Comment: I had that thought, too. I'm working with hundreds of thousands of lines, and I won't know beforehand what string to look for. Now its "job.no", 10 lines later it could be "task.no" or "xx9.ze". The only thing that makes sense to me is to look for periods within the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this recursive solution? Note that deeply nested dictionaries may not work due to standard Python's recursion limitation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# parse initial string
import json

def keyCleaner(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            d[key] = keyCleaner(value)
            if '.' in key:
                d[key.replace('.', '_')] = value
                del(d[key])
        return d
    if type(d) is list:
        return map(keyCleaner, d)
    if type(d) is tuple:
        return tuple(map(keyCleaner, d))
    return d

print keyCleaner(json.loads('{"uuid":"94e31-02f59","project":{"name":"oasis","job.no":215493452,"subset":"beta"},"time":1412371841024}'))
```

Comment: This is closer than I had gotten, but it looks like its only returning the last object of a nested array. This is the output `{u'project': (u'subset', u'beta'), u'uuid': u'94e31-02f59', u'time': 1412371841024L}`.

Comment: Added more handling. The idea is to replace each complex object that could potentially have more objects in it using recursion. It's used in hashing objects as well (but there is more to it when hashing).

Answer (score 1):

A less messy solution that worked for me (but you need to keep track of the modifications in your code) is to simply wrap the dictionary that contains the '.' inside a python list and store the list in mongo, instead of storing the dictionary (which throws the error).

```
new_item_to_store = list(dict_to_store.items())
```

I had the problem storing a dict of domains, i,e:

```
{"facebook.com": 2500,
"google.com" : 750,
"bing.com" : 200}
```

The above shows errors in mongo `store key 'job.no' must not contain '.'`, but this works fine:

```
[{"facebook.com": 2500,
"google.com" : 750,
"bing.com" : 200}]
```